# searching for a great php overview

Tags: php

as the title reads I'd like to find a webpage which presents an overview of the php language cause it's been a little while since I stopped to program server scripts.

By overview I see a page with the basic writing of the language (variable writing and the types, the control flows, some writing recommandations and some common functions about arrays and string manipulation) of course without the explicative text that generally comes with tutorials, I just want to refresh my memory about the basis.

I used google to find my request but not seeing anything like this on the first page.
I prefer asking here cause I trust in the stackoverflow community. If you have a personal page that refers to my wanting feel free to post back

**edit:** this sheet seems to be fine if you want php get the surface of your brain back 
http://www.emezeta.com/weblog/emezeta-php-card-v0.1.png

Comment: Add the search phrase "cheat sheet". Turned up lots of possibly-useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks I'm not an english native these two words are precious for me :)

Comment: One great source to find information is actually stackoverflow. Whatever specific problem you encounter, the answer is sure to be found on this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/phppr/chapter/php_pkt.html

Combined with this:

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/

One great source to find information is actually stackoverflow. Whatever specific problem you encounter, the answer is sure to be found on this site :)

Good luck, PHP is fun!